# Where to put uiautomator tests

Tags: android, testing, android-uiautomator

I am struggling where to put my uiautomator tests.  It seems like the most common place to to put it in the main project under a test folder.  And this is actually what Google recommends:

http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html#TestProjects

```
>   MyProject/
>       AndroidManifest.xml
>       res/
>           ... (resources for main application)
>       src/
>           ... (source code for main application) ...
>       tests/
>           AndroidManifest.xml
>           res/
>               ... (resources for tests)
>           src/
>               ... (source code for tests)
```

However when I do that I want to be able to add the uiautomator.jar to eclipse such that all sources in the tests folder build.  However I do not want the main project to depend on the uiauotmator.jar as well (ie it a test dependent jar only).

Does anyone else have a good idea on what to do here, or experience with a good way to setup the test project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

UIAautomator tests cannot be part of your application source code.
Its a separate application and you need to build a different binary (i.e. jar file)

The link you are referring is JUnit based tests, related to Instrumentation.